# How to create FaceList using some match threshold values in Microsoft Azure

Tags: python-3.x, azure, indexing, face-recognition

I wanted to create a face list in Azure. The condition is that:

```
if similarity_score < threshold:
   add to list
else:
   skip
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you add more insights about your requirement, as I understood, are you trying to find details about finding the similarity in face recognition?

Answer (score 1):

We can do the verification process for two images with below code, as here we have `.is_identical()`, this will confirm us about the result whether they are similar or not.

```
#Verification example for faces of different persons.
#Since target faces are same person, in this example, we can use the 1st ID in the detected_faces_ids list to compare.
verify_result_diff = face_client.face.verify_face_to_face(source_image2_id, detected_faces_ids[0])
print('Faces from {} & {} are of the same person, with confidence: {}'
    .format(source_image_file_name2, target_image_file_names[0], verify_result_diff.confidence)
    if verify_result_diff.is_identical
    else 'Faces from {} & {} are of a different person, with confidence: {}'
        .format(source_image_file_name2, target_image_file_names[0], verify_result_diff.confidence))
```

And with the below code we can able to find the match:

```
#Detect the faces in an image that contains multiple faces
#Each detected face gets assigned a new ID
multi_face_image_url = "http://www.historyplace.com/kennedy/president-family-portrait-closeup.jpg"
multi_image_name = os.path.basename(multi_face_image_url)
#We use detection model 3 to get better performance.
detected_faces2 = face_client.face.detect_with_url(url=multi_face_image_url, detection_model='detection_03')
```

Refer this Azure Python SDK for [Face Client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/client-libraries?pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=visual-studio)